# Mistake in javascript conditional if statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement, conditional-statements

I get an insure after uploading my PHP project into an internet host(000webhost.com). It works fine at my localhost but doesn't at internet host. Here is my code:

```
//view.php (use a hidden iframe to received data after submitting)
<form action="model.php" method="POST"  target="my_iframe" id="my_form" style="display: none;">
                <input type="hidden" name="user" id="user" value=""/>
                <input type="hidden" name="user_lastname" id="user_lastname" value=""/>
                <input type="hidden" name="user_firstname" id="user_lastname" value=""/>
            </form>
<iframe name="my_iframe" id="my_iframe" style="display: none;"></iframe>
<div id="sent">Sent</div>
<srcipt type="text/javascript">
    jQuery('#sent').unbind('click').click(funtion(){
        jQuery('#user').val("an user name");
        jQuery('#user_lastname').val("a last name");
        jQuery('#user_firstname').val("a first name");
        jQuery('#my_form').submit();
        jQuery('#my_iframe').unbind('load').load(function(){
            if(jQuery(this).contents().text()!='success')
               alert('Update failed');
            else
               alert('Update successful');
        });
     });

</script>

//model.php
if(UpdateUser($_REQUEST['user'],$_REQUEST['user_firstname']),$_REQUEST['user_lastname'])==true)
   echo 'success';
else
   echo 'Fail in updating';
```

At my localhost, i get an message "Update Successful" but at my internet host, i get an message "Update failed". Thank for advances. Sorry because of my bad English.

---EDIT----
I change style="display:block" of iframe to show its content. I see that iframe's content is "success" but i still get message "Update failed".it means:

Comment: You misspelled "script" in `<srcipt type="text/javascript">`. But I assume it's correct in the real script, or nothing would be running.

Comment: Have you checked the webserver log to see if model.php is being run? Is `UpdateUser` updating whatever it's supposed to update?

Comment: UpdateUser works fine. Database was updated correctly. How can i check the web server log?

Comment: If the database was updated, then the script was obviously run. Do you see the iframe updating with "success" if you inspect it with Firebug or Developer Tools? Why are you using a hidden iframe instead of using AJAX? Your whole mechanism seems to be very fragile, and iframes are deprecated.

Comment: Oh.because in my project i use a lot of input type="checkbox" to get selections from user. It is a English Test project. Its code is so long so i only show an same example here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I corrected the misspellings (there was another: function spelled "funtion" in the first line of the script).
The jQuery script is working so the problem must be with the PHP page. Maybe 000webhost puts some output before your PHP page's output or maybe that update is failing. Check the output of the PHP page.

Comment: Thank for checking my misspellings. But i don not understand  "check the out of php page" means. And i am sure that my function UpdateUser works correctly.

Comment: I mean that even if your UpdateUser function works correctly there is the possibility that the server outputs something extra other than 'success'. Since you used $_REQUEST you can call model.php directly and put parameters as get values (model.php?user=abc). This way you can check if model.php output is correct ( should only be 'success' - 7 chars, no more)

Comment: Thank a lot.i solved my problem by using trim() for string got from iframe.